# Issues with IAR 6.20

Tags: crash, iar

Did anyone started using IAR 6.20 on Windows 7 or XP?
I was using IAR 6.10 with no issues at all however, I am expereincing a lot of crashes and no response from IAR 6.20. Did anyone experience the same?

Comment: Yes, lots of people have used 6.20 without any problems. It is impossible to help you if you don't provide any more details. Have you contacted IAR support?

Comment: Yes, but I wanted to know if this issue is with us only. On XP it causes lots of crashes and slow to response as well. On Windows 7, there are no crashes but the compiling and download speed is too low.

Comment: IAR 6.20 for which target?  Are you referring to the version of Embedded workbench or the target compiler?  These are different.

Comment: IAR for which target processor? AVR? AVR32? MSP430? Coldfire? STM8? H8? 8051?.....

Comment: @PUnit: I haven't heard anything about any widespread problems with the ARM 6.20 release. If you are experiencing crashes, you should definitely contact IAR support. (By crashes, are you referring to the IDE crashing, or something else?)

Comment: Yes, IDE crashes and I have contacted them. But, it seems there is no issue with the IAR 6.20 as such, must be something wrong on the system.